Change the default tools (VS) for conan in Windows
I am learning conan under this page: https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/tools/cmake/cmake_toolchain/build_project_cmake_presets.html#examples-tools-cmake-toolchain-build-project-presets
I created a basic project based on the template cmake_exe as an example of a C++ project. After I input conan install .
The compiler shows this result:It doesn't find VS IDE. However, it already found the clang complier.
Error in CMD
I have two questions. Sorry, I am a fresher in the software development and may have some confusion about some tools concepts. Hope any expert can give me some idea to solve my problem.

As the profile build setting already found clang, Why does it try to use Visual Studio? I find something related to VS in the build file. Is it the root cause?

VS related code in the build folder

It seems it can use tools.microsoft.msbuild:vs_version to solve the problem, however I can't find any example in google. Is there any free tool I can choose? Maybe conan is not pointing to the complier.


LLVM/Clang in Windows uses MSVC (VS) backend and Clang can also be installed and used from the VS IDE, installed as a toolset. So VS is necessary. If you are not an expert, I'd strongly advice to install VS latest community edition, remove your .conan2 cache folder, and start from scratch, Conan should detect and use the msvc compiler. Also Github tickets in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues can be used for support from maintainers.

Please post the actual error message.

Hi @drodri. Thank you for your suggestion. The reason why I don't want to use VS is that  my company computer doesn't allow me to use VS community. I will try to use Linux instead.

Hi @nega, for the error message, you can find it in the bottom of the picture "Error in CMD". It is grateful if you have any further comment.

Please edit your post to include the actual error message, don't use images posted elsewhere. Images disappear over time, and that doesn't help anyone, lease of the the people who might be interested in helping you.

If you are still forced to use Windows and Clang at some point, but forbidden to use MSVC, then Msys2/Clang might be the solution, read https://blog.conan.io/2022/10/13/Different-flavors-Clang-compiler-Windows.html. Still, it is possible that some recipes from ConanCenter might not work with Msys2/Clang, as CI is not building that configuration, so not tested at all.
